# Gulp src order of files

Tags: javascript, sorting, gulp

Files in my directory:

```
1-icon.svg
2-icon.svg
3-icon.svg
10-icon.svg
11-icon.svg
12-icon.svg
20-icon.svg
21-icon.svg
22-icon.svg
```

Gulp src read them as:

```
1-icon.svg
10-icon.svg
11-icon.svg
12-icon.svg
2-icon.svg
20-icon.svg
21-icon.svg
22-icon.svg
3-icon.svg
```

I have tried gulp-sort and gulp-order but none of them gave me the exact order of files like my directory.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, gulp orders file same as strings could be ordered. To manage the ordering you can use `gulp-sort` plugin. Here is an example, I've done

```
const gulp = require('gulp'),
    debug = require('gulp-debug'),
    sort = require('gulp-sort'),
    path = require('path');

gulp.task('ordering', function() {

    return gulp.src('./test/*')
        .pipe(debug())
        .pipe(sort(customComparator))
        .pipe(debug())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));

});

function customComparator(f1, f2) {
    const f1Name = path.basename(f1.path);
    const f2Name = path.basename(f2.path);
    return Number(f1Name.split('-')[0]) > Number(f2Name.split('-')[0]) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Take a look at `customComparator` function which takes the first part of file name and created an order on the basis of it.

The `gulp-debug` plugin is used only to see the order of files in the console. So, the result looks as follows. You can see the list of files before and after ordering

```
$ npx gulp ordering
[18:54:27] Using gulpfile ~/own_projects/untitled/gulpfile.js
[18:54:27] Starting 'ordering'...
[18:54:27] gulp-debug: test/1-icon.svg
[18:54:27] gulp-debug: test/10-icon.svg
[18:54:27] gulp-debug: test/11-icon.svg
[18:54:27] gulp-debug: test/12-icon.svg
[18:54:27] gulp-debug: test/2-icon.svg
[18:54:27] gulp-debug: test/20-icon.svg
[18:54:27] gulp-debug: test/21-icon.svg
[18:54:27] gulp-debug: test/22-icon.svg
[18:54:27] gulp-debug: test/3-icon.svg
[18:54:27] gulp-debug: 9 items
[18:54:27] gulp-debug: test/1-icon.svg
[18:54:27] gulp-debug: test/2-icon.svg
[18:54:27] gulp-debug: test/3-icon.svg
[18:54:27] gulp-debug: test/10-icon.svg
[18:54:27] gulp-debug: test/11-icon.svg
[18:54:27] gulp-debug: test/12-icon.svg
[18:54:27] gulp-debug: test/20-icon.svg
[18:54:27] gulp-debug: test/21-icon.svg
[18:54:27] gulp-debug: test/22-icon.svg
[18:54:27] gulp-debug: 9 items
[18:54:28] Finished 'ordering' after 72 ms
```